# Using UISearchController in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to use search bar in my **tableviewcontroller**.But it is not entering if.

There is the code.

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    @try {
        [_searchResults removeAllObjects];
        NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name CONTAINS[cm] %@",searchController.searchBar.text];
        NSArray *array = [_customers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
        _searchResults = [array mutableCopy];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",exception);
    }
```

There is the resultsearchController

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchController *resultSearchController;
```

And `numberofRowsinsection` method.

```
if (![[self resultSearchController] isActive]) {
        return _customers.count;
    } else {
        return _searchResults.count;
    }
```

I am added Cellforindexpath method too.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    KartList *kart;
    if (_resultSearchController.active) {
        kart = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = kart.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = kart.tel1;
        return cell;
    } else {
        kart = [_customers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = kart.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = kart.tel1;
        return cell;
    }



    //Configure the cell...


}
```

It's not showing anything.So what I am doing wrong.And I am seeing its not entering else clause in numberOfRowsInSection.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: have you checked : updateSearchResultsForSearchController? is it returning correct array? also, can you post cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your UITableView's delegate and datasource to self.

Try:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
// do then whatever else
}
```